# Selecting all projects and tasks for a specific userID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all Projects and Tasks from my database when given a specific userID.

The tables are as follows:

```
Users: UserID
Projects: ProjectID, UserID
Tasks: TaskID, ProjectID
```

I've tried things with nested queries, table joins and such but I'm no SQL expert by far and I'm struggling to get what I need. I can get all Tasks from a specific userID but that uses an Inner Join on the ProjectID which means that it doesn't return Projects that have 0 Tasks as Projects with no Tasks have nothing to be joined with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to return the data:

```
select *
from users u
left join projects p
    on u.userid = p.userid
left join tasks t
    on p.projectid = t.projectid
where u.userid = ?
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af62f/1)

This will return all users regardless of whether they have records in the `projects` or `tasks` table.